# One2Many count continue ondefault one2many unlink

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-6

I need to count the no of records in one2many which i am able to do by using the method:

```
def update_cust(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):
    current_obj = self.browse(cr,uid,ids[0])
    one2many_ids=self.pool.get('customer.test').search(cr,uid,[], count=True)

    if one2many_ids==0:
        one2many_ids=1
        count=one2many_ids
    elif one2many_ids<11:
        one2many_ids=one2many_ids+1
        count=one2many_ids
    elif one2many_ids==11:
        return True
    elif not one2many_ids:
        count=one2many_ids=11
    else:
        one2many_ids=12
        count=one2many_ids
    self.pool.get('customer.test').create(cr,uid,{
                            'cust_id':current_obj.id,
                            'customer':current_obj.customer.id,
                            'street':current_obj.street,
                            'phone':current_obj.phone,
                            'cust_address':current_obj.cust_address.id,
                            'code':count-1
                    })
    return True
```

Although what i need to do is, incase one unlinks a record and add a new record the next record must continue from 11... &the total number of records in one2many must be 10 at most 
one2many definition & class definition:

```
class customer_test(osv.osv):
    _name="customer.test"
    _columns={
            'customer':fields.many2one('res.partner','Customers',ondelete="cascade"),
            'cust_id':fields.many2one('customer.test','CustId'),
            'street':fields.char('Street',size=40),
            'phone':fields.integer('Phone'),
            'cust_address':fields.many2one('res.partner.address','Address'),
            'cust_address2':fields.many2one('res.partner.address','Secondary Address'),
            'cust_one2many':fields.one2many('customer.test','cust_id',''),
            'code' : fields.integer('Code'),
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    def update_cust(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):
    current_obj = self.pool.get('customer.test').browse(cr,uid,ids[0])
    code=current_obj.code+1
    count=one2many_ids=self.pool.get('customer.test').search(cr,uid,[('cust_id','=',current_obj.id)], count=True)
    vals=self.pool.get('customer.test').search(cr,uid,[('id','=',current_obj.id)])
    sequence_obj = self.pool.get('customer.test')
    seq_id = sequence_obj.search(cr, uid, [('id', '=', current_obj.id)])   
    if count==0:
        sequence_obj.write(cr, uid, seq_id, {'code': 1})      
    while current_obj.id in vals and count < 10:
        sequence=self.pool.get('customer.test').browse(cr,uid,ids[0]).code
        self.pool.get('customer.test').create(cr,uid,{
                'cust_id':current_obj.id,
                'customer':current_obj.customer.id,
                'street':current_obj.street,
                'phone':current_obj.phone,
                'cust_address':current_obj.cust_address.id,
                'code':sequence})
        sequence_obj.write(cr, uid, seq_id, {'code': sequence+1})      
        return True
    return True
```

Thats the solution for my question